# Cannot figure out z index issue, trying to place graphic text over image that is positioned to the bottom right of section

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to avoid using position absolute for my mobile-first, responsive website./ [image: graphic text and image] I am having a tough time getting the h1 and p tag in front of the image. With position absolute comes more troubles down the road, so I would like to avoid that. Also any advice for dealing with those svg lines or should I remove them?  Here's my code:

```css
.climate {
    padding: 2em 1em 5rem;
}

.reverse {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
    color: var(--clr-light);
    z-index: 10;
}

.disaster-graphic {
    background-color: var(--clr-background);
} 


.graphic-image {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: -150px 0 0 205px;
    padding: 0;
}

.greenroof {
    max-width: 600px;
    
}
```

```html
<section class="climate disaster-graphic">
       
            <h2 class="reverse">Reverse the climate disaster</h2>
            <p class="orange">Learn what it takes to bring your business to the next level.</p>
       
        <div class="graphic-image">
                <img src="/images/greene 1.png" class="greenroof">
            </div>
```

Comment: your question isn't clear can you explain more you want the text on the image without using position absolute and why without position absolute

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all the CSS required for this example. Your variables aren't going to work because you're not showing us the root values. Also, if change out your local image path for something online. Get the dimensions of your image and use something like [https://placekitten.com](https://placekitten.com) to add an image of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` can be tricky. Unfortunately, when working with `z-index` you *have* to at least position the element of which you are trying to move along the z-axis. Some helpful reading about `z-index`:

> [4 reasons your z-index isn't working (and how to fix it)](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/)

To solve your problem, you can simply add `position: relative` to your `.graphic-image`. Furthermore, change it's `z-index` from `1` to `-1`. Lastly, you do not need to have a `z-index: 10` on `.reverse`. On elements where `z-index` is not specified, it is set to `auto` (`0`). So in this case `-1 < 0`.

*I used a placeholder image and also changed the color of your text just so you can see it in front of the image.*

Regarding your "SVG lines", you'll have to post some more code to get further assistance with that issue.

```css
body{
  color: goldenrod; /* to be removed, just so you can see the text in front of image */
}
.climate {
  padding: 2em 1em 5rem;
}

.reverse {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
  color: var(--clr-light);
  /*remove z-index: 10 */
}

.disaster-graphic {
  background-color: var(--clr-background);
}

.graphic-image {
  z-index: -1; /*change z-index to -1*/
  margin: -150px 0 0 205px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; /*add position*/
}

.greenroof {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section class="climate disaster-graphic">

  <h2 class="reverse">Reverse the climate disaster</h2>
  <p class="orange">Learn what it takes to bring your business to the next level.</p>

  <div class="graphic-image">
<!-- placeholder image -->
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" class="greenroof">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` only sets the z-order of a **positioned element** or a flex item. That is to say `z-index` does nothing unless either you specify the `position` of the element or the element is a flex item. In your case neither of those are true so z-index does nothing.

The easiest solution is to simply add `position: relative` to `.reverse` and `.orange`.

I've quickly put together [a working codepen for context](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/MWVNPrL).

Regarding the svg lines, there are many ways you could deal with them but it depends what your goal is. I am going to assume you always want them "attached" to the orange box like in the image you've shared but don't want their existence to impact the layout of the rest of the elements.

That being the case, I would suggest using `position: absolute` on the svg with the svg element being a direct child of `.orange` (which you will have now added `position:relative` to solve your z-index issue). This will "attach" the svg to the orange box so that wherever the orange box goes, the green lines go too. It would be helpful to see more of your code so that part of your question could be answered in more detail.

Personally I would have made the orange box an element and placed the `<p>` tag inside it rather than styling the `<p>` to look like text inside and orange box. You may have had a reason for doing it your way though. The codepen I added above contains my solution for the svg lines by the way.